# If a sequence $\{a_n\}$ satisfies the Inequality $a_{n+1} < ka_{n}$, then show that $ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n =0$ where $0< k , a_n< 1$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

I know one solution.

Consider $\sum a_n$

Then use ratio test to show that the series converges, hence the sequence.

Any other Ideass !

Comment: You should add the condition $a_n \ge 0$.

Comment: By the way, proving that $\sum a_n$ converges and hence $a_n\rightarrow 0$ is bit too much.

Comment: Yes and no: look at @martini's proof below: from his conclusion to the stronger claim that $\sum_n a_n$ converges there is an infinitesimal step. You can stop before that, but the proof is actually the same.

Comment: @martini added a_n > 0

Answer (score 2):

I will suppose $a_n \ge 0$, as otherwise the statement is wrong.

By induction, we have $a_n < k^na_0$, hence $0 \le a_n \le k^n a_0$. As $0 \to 0$ and $k^n a_0 \to 0$ (we have $k \in (0,1)$), by the squeeze theorem $a_n \to 0$.

Answer (score -1):

we have a theorem if a sequence is bounded and descend this sequence ins convergence and this condition is true for your question .and i think we have $a_n\geq 0 $

Comment: -1. The limit coincides with the infimum of the sequence, and you must prove that in this case the infimum is zero. If you try, you'll see that it is not trivial.

Comment: i can't understand because we have $k,a_n\geq0 $and$1\geq k,a_n $ and ok all condition

Comment: Your proof is rather incomplete: okay, we can say that $a_n \to \ell \geq 0$. But now you need to show that $\ell =0$. My previous comment was a bit tough, since you can pass to the limit in $a_{n+1} \leq k a_n$ and deduce that $\ell \leq k\ell$, so that $(1-k)\ell \leq 0$ and hence $\ell=0$.